# How to select from a dropdown list in WebExecute?

Tags: webservices, automation, webdriver, web-access

After locating the dropdown using the XPath as follows:

```
element=First@WebExecute["LocateElements"->"XPath"->"..."];
```

How do I select something from the drop-down list?

Is there a "SelectIndex" that I can use to select from a dropdown list as follows:

```
WebExecute["SelectIndex"->{element,2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the XPath of the option you want to select, and then use `"ClickElement"` for that option